# How to add columns from one data frame to other based on specific rule

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine table from https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2127.html with https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2004rank.html.

So in order to create 2 data frames I do the following:

```
url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world- 
factbook/fields/2127.html'
url2 = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world- 
factbook/rankorder/2004rank.html'
d = {'TOTAL FERTILITY RATE(CHILDREN BORN/WOMAN)':'TFR'}
d2 = {'Country','GDP - PER CAPITA (PPP)':'GDP (PPP)'}
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0].rename(columns=d)
df2 = pd.read_html(url2, header=0)[0].rename(columns=d2)
df['TFR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TFR'].str[:-31])
```

Now I create a sub dataframe from df2 :

```
df21 = df2[['Country','GDP (PPP)']]
```

So I end up with df21 that contains country names and their GDP. Now I'd like to compare two data frames and assign values in GDP (PPP) to each country in df based on their name (in both df and df2 there is a column that contain country name). Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df3 = df.merge(df2[['Country','GDP (PPP)']], how='left')
print (df3.head())
          Country   TFR GDP (PPP)
0     Afghanistan  5.12    $2,000
1         Albania  1.51   $12,500
2         Algeria  2.70   $15,200
3  American Samoa  2.68   $11,200
4         Andorra  1.40   $49,900
```

---

```
df['GDP (PPP)'] = df['Country'].map(df2.set_index('Country')['GDP (PPP)'])
print (df.head())
          Country   TFR GDP (PPP)
0     Afghanistan  5.12    $2,000
1         Albania  1.51   $12,500
2         Algeria  2.70   $15,200
3  American Samoa  2.68   $11,200
4         Andorra  1.40   $49,900
```

If country values from `df2['Country']` not exist in `df['Country']` was created `NaN`:

```
print (df[df['GDP (PPP)'].isna()])
                     Country   TFR GDP (PPP)
43          Christmas Island   NaN       NaN
44   Cocos (Keeling) Islands   NaN       NaN
78                Gaza Strip  4.13       NaN
154           Norfolk Island   NaN       NaN
165         Pitcairn Islands   NaN       NaN
191                  Somalia  5.80       NaN
198                 Svalbard   NaN       NaN
230                    World  2.42       NaN
```